# Copying a link from Tridion online Documentation

Tags: documentation

I am trying to copying a link as mentioned in Tridion doc for mailing but unable to do that. Please see the attached screenshot. Can someone point out how to copy a clean link. Copying a URL contains lot of query parameter making it look bad.

Example:
[http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL Tridion 2013 full documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-6C191FAA-9007-4CD6-BB0B-521DCA2CE95F&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-6C191FAA-9007-4CD6-BB0B-521DCA2CE95F.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-6C191FAA-9007-4CD6-BB0B-521DCA2CE95](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%202013%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-6C191FAA-9007-4CD6-BB0B-521DCA2CE95F&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-6C191FAA-9007-4CD6-BB0B-521DCA2CE95F.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-6C191FAA-9007-4CD6-BB0B-521DCA2CE95F)F

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it as shown in pic below, it will give you a URL with a GUID like : http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-F792AB1A-060A-4757-802D-3A2DB18F022D

For Internet Explorer, use "Copy Shortcut" option, as shown in question image.

[image]